# Expecting to identify the usage of Expo router instead of using React Native terminal directly to build the mobile app

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm a newbie to React Native mobile application developing. I have seen many YouTube tutorials about using Expo router instead of React Native terminal to build the app. Can someone please tell me why it is more efficient to use Expo router instead of React Native terminal directly? I have build a Weather forecasting application with Expo but still not quite getting the idea of it.